# Conceptual proofs to seven color theorem of torus for 17-19 year olds

Tags: general-topology, coloring

what is the best way to explain the seven color theorem of torus to some high school kids and freshman college people?

Comment: The main thing is to get a large, but light, torus, and draw the seven regions in colors that can be readily differentiated. Bicycle tubes are too narrow. Maybe a child's inflatable swimming life preserver. It may take a couple of tries to get it right. Matching diagram in the plane mod $\mathbb Z^2$

Comment: Thank you very much. so can we assume the upper bound? I saw a cute proof in a dover publication. However my memory fails me now.

Comment: http://store.doverpublications.com/0486417417.html

Comment: I do not think this was the book.

Comment: http://search.doverpublications.com/search?keywords=graph%20theory

Comment: Sorry. Could not locate in the list provided.